# Why is runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests enabled by default in the VS2012 MVC4 project skeleton

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have noticed that `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is `true` by default in the VS2012 MVC4 project skeleton.  Does anybody know why? What feature requires this setting?

Answer (score 0):

This setting has effect only if you are running in Integrated Pipeline mode in IIS. If you are running in Classic mode it will be ignored. If you set it to `true` then all integrated HTTP modules will run on every request. For example not only for .aspx pages but also for static files such as .jpg .gif .css .html .pdf, ... So enabling this might have a performance effect on your website.

Comment: This is true, but the question is asking *why* the MVC4 project template has RAMMFAR enabled.

Comment: How the hell am I supposed to know that? It's a question you should ask the designers of the framework. I have explained what this setting means and why it could have negative impact on the performance of your application if you leave it that way. No feature in the basic template that I am aware of requires it. The first thing I always do when I start a new application is to make sure that this setting is set to `false`.

Comment: I agree that any answer would be speculative (at best). "Why did they do it this way"-style questions are problematic for that reason. Still, your statement "No feature in the basic template that I am aware of requires it" is useful, and you should include it in your answer. :)